# Ограничение вывода цикла в консоль

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Скажите пожалуйста, почему при создании подобного цикла в консоль выводится только около 300 итераций? А конкретно с 701 по 999. Почему не выводятся все 1000?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: [Уверены?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YXsQcx). Ищите в другом месте вашей программы проблему, данный код не приведет к подобным последствиям.

Comment: А программы как таковой и нет. Единственное что есть сейчас в моем коде - это этот цикл. Быть может в самой студии какое то ограничение установлено? Я только начал обучаться, поэтому извиняюсь заранее за возможно глупые вопросы.

Comment: Первый раз слышу об ограничениях и с подобным не разу не сталкивался. Может кто знающий вам ответит...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ограничения на вывод нет, но есть ограничение на отображение вывода. Ограничение связано с размером буфера вывода системной консоли. При последовательном выводе строк, начиная с некоторого количества, новые выводимые строки начинают затирать самые старые. Размером буфера можно управлять как на уровне системы (правый клик по шапке окна консоли => Свойства), так и на уровне приложения (см. [Console.BufferHeight](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferheight?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Console.BufferWidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferwidth?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Но прежде чем увеличивать буфер вывода, стоит подумать о том, что для анализа полученных результатов, если их много, проще и удобнее использовать даже обычные текстовые файлы, чем листать "километровый" буфер консоли.